# How to read Windows command 'query user' response using subprocess in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Disclaimer:  I am a newb, so, forgive me if this seems misguided, but I did search for an answer to all of this first...

I would like to ultimately run the "query user" command and use the returned output in python version 3.7.x - No matter what subprocess method I use, I cannot get this done for some reason.

I have had some success doing this in python version 3.6.  However, using the same code in python version 3.7 does not work.

```
import subprocess

no_window = 0x08000000
cmd_to_run = "quser /server:ServerName"
results = 
 subprocess.Popen(cmd_to_run,shell=True,creationflags=no_window,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

print(results)
```

I expect this to simply print an unformatted response of the quser command.  It does, in python 3.6.  In python 3.7, it displays:

> (b'', None)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not appear to be a problem with Python 3.7.6 or newer.  I was able to use the proposed code successfully today, 2020JAN02.